# Is it possible to change how the OpacityMask property targets the control in a style

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles, opacitymask

My idea is to use a WPF default button use an image as the opacity mask and have the foreground brush change its color. I want to still have the background however and this is where the issue is, because no matter how I design the style the background always disappears. Either this isn’t possible because the opacity Mask cannot change its target and just acts on the entire control or I am missing something.

Here is the style i have. I am trying to keep it fairly basic.

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">

    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource Mono_Darkest}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource Mono_Light}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource Button_BorderBrush_Normal}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource Button_BorderThickness_Normal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource Button_FontFamily_Normal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="{StaticResource Button_FontWeight_Normal}"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource Button_FontSize_Normal}"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="{StaticResource Button_HorizontalContentAlignment_Normal}"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="{StaticResource Button_VerticalContentAlignment_Normal}"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="{StaticResource Button_Padding_Normal}"/>

    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Border x:Name="Border_Part" 
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Label OpacityMask="{TemplateBinding OpacityMask}" 
                               Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
                               VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" 
                               Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" 
                               FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}">
                            <Label.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="Label">
                                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=OpacityMask, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Converter={StaticResource isNull}}" 
                                                     Value="false">
                                            <Setter Property="Background" 
                                                    Value="{Binding Path=Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
                                        </DataTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>
                            </Label.Style>
                        </Label>
                    </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I have is simply nesting a label inside the border. What I want is the template (Button) control's opacity property to only affect the label's opacity property. But that doesn’t seem to be happening. Instead it seems to affect everything like the default button style would.

I have tried Setting OverridesDefaultStyle to True but that has not changed anything.

I know I can already do this other ways. But my goal is to just make a quick button that can use either text or images as a foreground. With the image color coming from the foreground brush. If I cannot get an answer here I am most likely just going to use an Attached Property and bind the labels opacity mask to that instead, but again I would rather just do it entirely in this style.

Any advice is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: U r asking `What I want is the template (Button) control's opacity property to only affect the label's opacity property.` and ur question title asking something else.

Comment: break ur question into small sub-questions and ask one by one.

Answer (score 0):

For `Opacity` I use a `Converter`. With this I can bind a `SolidColorBrush` to `Foreground` or `Background`. The `Converter` gets a `Parameter` with the target `Opacity` and returns the opac color.

**Converter:**

```
public class ColorToOpacityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    // Takes a SolidColorBrush as value and double as parameter
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (!(value is SolidColorBrush)) return value;
        SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(((SolidColorBrush) value).Color);
        scb.Opacity = parameter as double? ?? 0.5;
        return scb;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**xaml:**

```
<Style.Resources>
    <namespace:ColorToOpacityConverter x:Key="ColorToOpacityConverter" />
    <system:Double x:Key="TargetOpacity">0.3</system:Double>
</Style.Resources>

<Label Foreground="{Binding Path=Foreground, StaticResource={StaticResource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource ColorToOpacityConverter}, ConverterParameter={StaticResource TargetOpacity}"
```

A second approach for bound opacities (not as `StaticResource`) I use a `MultiValueConverter`

**For bound opacities:**

```
public class ColorToDynOpacityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values.Any(v => v == DependencyProperty.UnsetValue)) return new SolidColorBrush();
        if (!(values[0] is SolidColorBrush) || !(values[1] is double)) {
            //Fake for DesignMode-Display
            if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(new DependencyObject())) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua);
            throw new ArgumentException("expect values[0] as SolidColorBrush and values[1] as double.");
        }
        SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(((SolidColorBrush) values[0]).Color);
        scb.Opacity = (double) values[1];
        return scb;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**xaml:**

```
<namespace:ColorToDynOpacityConverter x:Key="ColorToDynOpacityConverter" />

<Label>
    <Label.Foreground>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ColorToDynOpacityConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Foreground" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
            <Binding Path="Opacity" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Label.Foreground>
</Label>
```

Hope that helps and working for you.